# SharePoint list workflow page cannot open

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

When I select item and click Workflow, error page throws `Something went wrong`. And in log found

> Application error when access /_layouts/15/Workflow.aspx, Error=No
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it.

Any suggestion how to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you try reconfiguring the Workflow Manager, it might solve the problem

Comment: This might help too https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88517/error-when-manually-starting-migrated-2007-workflows-in-sp-2013